# how to check in c that a particular letter was pressed?

Tags: c

can someone please tell me how to check in c that a particular letter was pressed ?
I want to check if the letter 'r' was pressed. here is a small part of my code, where I need to check if it was pressed.

```
ch = getch();
if(ch==r)
    i=1;
else
    i=2;
```

the program considers the 'r' in my 'if' as a variable, but I want it to be considered as a letter so I would be able to check if it was pressed. can someone please tell me how to do that ?

Comment: You can't "press letters" in C. You can, however, in a letter press.

Comment: If you are checking true or false, you may want to use 0 for false, and 1 for true. Then you can later reference it as `if(i)` and will execute the code block only if i == 1.

Answer (score 2):

Put the 'r' in single quotes:

```
ch = getch();
if(ch=='r')
  i=1;
else
  i=2;
```